# javascript to control css positioning

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following script in my page to close out a dropdown submenu when    the close button is clicked:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".closebutton").click(function() {
      clearTimeout();
      var c = $(this).closest("li");
      c.find(".dropdown").css("left", "-9999px")
    });
  });
</script>
```

Once the "close button" is pressed, the dropdown no longer appears again when I hover over the parent li since the css has been changed to "left: -9999px". What script should I add that returns the css to "left: 0px;" again when I hover once more on the parent li without reloading the page?

Thanks!

Comment: With hovering again, you mean a simple hover? Since your first action is a click. So according to that, you would use `.hover()` to return its value back to `left: 0;`

Comment: @Aer0 the hover to trigger the dropdown initially is CSS-based, and once the dropdown submenu is open, there is a close button within the submenu box that closes it on click

Comment: use this instead $("dropdownSelector").hide();

Comment: Hi @HasanDaghash, thanks but I cannot change the design, as it's an existing site and I'm just adding a landing page for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finds the closest li to the close button, and when its hovered finds the .dropdown element and sets the .dropdown to left: 0.

```
$('.closebutton').closest('li').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown').css('left', '0px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.show()` and `.hide()` events in jQuery rather than changing the css and the `.hover()` to execute the `.show()`.

```
c.find(".dropdown").hide();
```

Comment: Thanks @plottydotty, I cannot change the design, as it's an existing site and I'm just adding a landing page for it so it has to work the same as the existing one. The existing navigation menu is javascript-controlled as well but I couldn't use script for that as it was too long to put in the head section. I'm just doing a single landing page separate from the main site's system

Comment: CKH4's solution works perfectly, but thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `$.mouseover()` event and change the `left` property back to `0px`. It would look something like this:

```
'<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".closebutton").mouseover(function() {
            var d = $(this).closest("li");
            d.find(".dropdown").css("left", "0px");
        });
    });
</script>'
```

Hope that helps!